# Get data using find() in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a field : `post`

```
                  id                                                userId
    2beaa4b5-4c53-4652-b2c3-34ecfe627acd            9beaa3b5-4c53-4f52-b2c3-49ecfe627ebf
    4dfaa4b5-3r45-4652-b2c3-34ecfewsa345            f45aa3b5-4c53-4f52-b2c3-49ecfe543bde
```

post model :

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'post';
    protected $keyType = 'string';
    public $incrementing = false;
    protected $connection = 'product';
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

In controller, I get user by userId :

```
$user = Post::where('userId', '9beaa3b5-4c53-4f52-b2c3-49ecfe627ebf')->get();
```

Is there any other way to get the `userId` other than **where**? eg **find**? Please give me your opinion. Thanks.

Comment: `find()` uses the model's primary key. (`->find('value')` is equivalent to `->whereKey('value')->first()`). If you want a single result returned, just use `first()` instead of `get()` but you will still have to use `where()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find()` is just a shorthand for adding a `where()` clause on the primary key field and executing the query. That is, `Post::find($id)` == `Post::where('id', $id)->first()`.

Calling `get()` will always return a `Collection`, even if there are no results. I'm assuming that your query is meant to only return one record. If that is the case, you'll want to use `first()` instead of `get()`, as that will either return the one found record, or it will return `null` if there are no records.

```
$user = Post::where('userId', '9beaa3b5-4c53-4f52-b2c3-49ecfe627ebf')->first();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Laravel Relationships. On your Post model add:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'userId');
}
```

And in your User model you can add:

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class, 'userId');
}
```

Now if you're using the `$user` variable, you can get all the posts of that user like this:

```
$posts = $user->posts()->get();
```

And vice versa, if you have a `$post`, you can get the $user like this:

```
$user = $post->user;
```

More info here:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships